# CSS effect inside PHP code

Tags: php, html, css

I have written some HTML code inside PHP with echo as below:

```
            echo '<a class = "fragment" href = "'.$row['url'].'" target = "_blank" >';
            echo '<div>';
            echo "Title: $title"; echo '<br/>';
            echo "URL:"; echo '<h4>' .$url. '</h4>';
            echo "Preview : $preview"; echo '<br/>';
            echo "Image url: $image"; echo '<br/>';
            echo '</br>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</a>';
```

Problem is `$url` appears on a new line and in bold text. Though i have not used here `<b>` or `<br/>` before and after it.

How can I show it like

```
URL : www.url.com
```

same like other parameters appears?

CSS effect appears properly.

css for h4:

```
.fragment h4 
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        color: #000;
    }

    .fragment h4:hover 
    {
        background-color:#ccc;
        text-decoration: underline; 
    }
```

Comment: set `h4` to have `font-weight:normal`

Comment: @Morpheus: thanks. Like `text-decoration: font-weight-normal ` right?

Comment: Like `h4 { font-weight: normal; }`

Comment: @Programming_crazy it was a typo, fixed above comment

Comment: Why would you place an echo foreach HTML line?

Comment: @MarkkNijboer: I was not knowing that there's other way before.

Comment: Now carrying previous implementation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `h4` tag is (a) a heading tag (hence the boldness) and (b) a block-level tag (hence the new line). If you don't want these aspects, why are you using it?

If you want to style this text, you should use the tag provided for the purpose: `<span>`. Give it a `class` or an `id` and style that.